# How to get dropdown like menu in wp7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Hello I've been looking for a solution to create a menu that is available in Windows Phone 7. An example is when you adjust the brightness on the phone there is a dropdown control that opens when you click on it. I think I've found a way before but I can't seem to get to it again. Has anyone found any resources on doing this or maybe has a suggestion on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you talking about the `ListPicker` control from the [Silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291)? If so, these articles describe its use:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx
- http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth
- http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/customizing-listpicker-for-wp7-part1

Comment: Wow I can't believe this escaped me. I had no idea this was part of control toolkit. The strange thing is my toolbox doesn't show this control. I'll have to see what's going on with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the Toolkit installed.
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291

Comment: Yeah that would make sense. I knew it wasn't part of the standard toolbox. Many thanks.