# Proper way to implement a dropdownbox in WP7 ?

Tags: windows-phone-7, drop-down-menu, styles

I have seen 2 ways.

1. Fake a ASP.NET stlye and have the options appear over a textbox on the same screen.
2. When the box is touched open a new screen that lets you scroll through all options and pick one. When one is selected that value is copied to the placeholder on the orginal screen.

I am working on a project where we are doing #1 and I am thinking #2 is the proper way ?

Comment: I see. So my question then is. When is it proper to go full screen vs. stay in the same screen?  I was looking on MSDN for the WP7 design guide and it did tseem to talk about this

Comment: Guessing you're referring to the Silverlight Toolkit - The ListPicker will automatically expand to full size when you have > 5 items, otherwise it happens inline. The Toolkit is created by Windows Phone developers at Microsoft, so you can bet it matches the design suggestions :)

Comment: ok thanks. thats what i was looking for.. I didnt know it was automatic.. I thought it would be left up to the programmer since sometimes a Listpicker with be alone so there is room to expand it.. other times maybe there are textboxes below and above it so it would be too crowded to show even 3  options on the same screen..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ListPicker` from the silverlight toolkit if you're looking to match the WP7 paradigm (which you should want to :) )

[Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)

Comment: ListPicker is definitely what you want, it suppots both `Settings::Theme::Accent Color` style and `Settings::Theme::Theme` style selection modes.

Answer (score 1):

These other stackoverflow questions may provide some insight (possible duplicate?):

[How to get dropdown like menu in wp7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363669/how-to-get-dropdown-like-menu-in-wp7)

[Windows Phone Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654599/windows-phone-dropdown)

Don't forget to use the search function at the top right hand before asking a question!

Comment: Ok I read this. The first expands in place to give you options. Useful for short lists. The second takes you over to another page witha full listbox to choose from then returns to the calling screen.